# ptrace usage in ARM

Tags: c, linux, arm, ptrace, imx7

I'm trying to analyse how a third party software is controlling some hardware. The board is i.mx7 based running i.MX Linux kernel 3.14.52.

The board is a development board and is running some demo software which I do not have the code for. Most of the configuration is done via `ioctl` calls and I've trying to use `strace` to learn more about information is being set/get.

As an example I get the following from `strace`:

`ioctl(4, FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO, 0x19fcebc)`

I would like in some way to dereference the pointer in the third argument to see the data. I know the structure of the data, and from what I've read, if `strace` doesn't already know your structure, then you have no luck.

I have also read about writing my own code using `ptrace` to do something similar, but every single example is not for ARM. The code I've seen uses `ORIG_EAX` and `EAX` registers and ARM I believe uses `orig_r` and `r7`, but I have no idea how to access the "registers". I'm quite new to programming for Linux.

What's surprising is I can't even easily find anything in exhaustive Googling. Some threads allude to it but I cannot find specifics. I can't be the only person who needs to use `ptrace` on ARM? Admittedly I might be the only person trying to use it you don't know how!

Failing getting `ptrace` working, I would be happy just peeking at the memory where the `strace` indicates the structures are and I could rebuild them manually. How would I go about this?

Thanks for any hints or pointers, I'm really hitting a brick wall.

Comment: You might want to try looking though strace [source code](https://github.com/strace/strace/tree/master/linux/arm) or maybe even adapting it to your needs.

Comment: You can attach gdb and dump the memory.

Comment: Besides different registers, ptrace on arm is pretty much the same as on x86. For memory reading you'd use PTRACE_PEEKDATA. As you've already considered, I think the easiest way would be to adjust strace to print ioctl buffer data (do note that it does not actually have to be a buffer, it could just be an int argument).

Comment: Thanks guys. I did as you suggested and simply adapted strace for my needs. For anyone with similar issues just look at the source file ioctl.c. In SYS_FUNC(ioctl) (strace v5.2) you can find what you need and I used printnum_int() to output the number of values I needed. When I have more time I'll look further into how the ARM ptrace registers are used within strace..